# Showing primefaces overlay panel leads to NPE in Mojarra code

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2, mojarra

I use a `p:overlayPanel` on several places. It offers values from which the user can choose. This overlay panel is parameterized and used on several places. Therefore I show the panel with a click on a button like this:

```
<p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('overlayPanelVar').loadContents('#{component.clientId}');" immediate="true" actionListener="#{myController.setSelectedObject(curMaskElement, curDummyCssClass)}" process="@this" />
```

This works but only in one case I get a `NullPointerException` in JSF implementation mojarra this `commandButton` was created inside `ui:repeat`.
When the user clicks on the button it works and overlay panel appears, but if a value is chosen from the overlay panel (which is a link) this happens:

```
15:16:30,873 SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (http-/0.0.0.0:9090-5) null: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.restoreChildState(UIRepeat.java:433) [jsf-impl-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.restoreChildState(UIRepeat.java:448) [jsf-impl-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.restoreChildState(UIRepeat.java:415) [jsf-impl-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:546) [jsf-impl-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.invokeOnComponent(UIRepeat.java:695) [jsf-impl-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:714) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:1503) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:714) [jsf-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.invokeOnComponent(UIRepeat.java:697) [jsf-impl-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
```

The code in mojarra UIReapeat.class:

```
private void restoreChildState(FacesContext faces, UIComponent c) {
    // reset id
    String id = c.getId();
    c.setId(id);

    // hack
    if (c instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
        EditableValueHolder evh = (EditableValueHolder) c;
        String clientId = c.getClientId(faces);
        SavedState ss = this.getChildState().get(clientId);
        if (ss != null) {
            ss.apply(evh);
        } else {
            String childId = clientId.substring(initialClientId.length() + 1);
            childId = childId.substring(childId.indexOf(getSeparatorChar(faces)) + 1);
            childId = initialClientId + getSeparatorChar(faces) + childId;
            if (initialChildState.containsKey(childId)) {
                SavedState initialState = initialChildState.get(childId);
                initialState.apply(evh);
            } else {
                NullState.apply(evh);
            }
        }
    }

    // continue hack
    Iterator itr = c.getFacetsAndChildren();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        restoreChildState(faces, (UIComponent) itr.next());
    }
}
```

The `initialClientId` member is null.
This appears with version 2.2.12.
If I change the JSF implementation of JBoss 6.2 to bundled which comes with JBoss this exception does not occur. The jars are `jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar` and `jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar`.

In another usage of the overlay panel I create the `commandButton` inside a `h:dataTable` iteration and it works.
This is probably a mojarra bug?

The NPE occurs when the `commandButton` is created like this:

```
<p:panelGrid styleClass="searchMaskFieldsGrid">
    <ui:repeat value="#{curSearch.getSearchMaskDescription().getRows()}" var="curRow" varStatus="rowStatus">
        <p:row styleClass="searchMaskRow">
            <ui:repeat value="#{curRow.elements}" var="curMaskElement" varStatus="colStatus">
                <p:column colspan="#{curMaskElement.columnSpan}"
                    styleClass="#{curMaskElement.isLabel() ? 'searchMaskLabelColumn' : 'searchMaskInputColumn'}">

                    <!-- this includes one field and here can be the commandButton be added -->
                    <ui:include src="/sections/search/searchFields.xhtml">
                        <ui:param name="curMaskElement" value="#{curMaskElement}" />
                        <ui:param name="curRowIndex" value="#{rowStatus.index}" />
                        <ui:param name="curColumnIndex" value="#{colStatus.index}" />
                    </ui:include>
                </p:column>
            </ui:repeat>
            <ui:param name="unfilledColumnsCount" value="#{searchBL.determinedUnfilledColumns(curSearch.getSearchMaskDescription(), curRow)}" />
            <p:column colspan="#{unfilledColumnsCount}" rendered="#{unfilledColumnsCount gt 0}">
                <h:outputLabel value="" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Is it maybe a known limitation with `PF('overlayPanelVar').loadContents('#{component.clientId}');` and `ui:repeat` and someone knows a workaround?

Comment: PrimeFaces 1.3 is not supported anymore. And can you try to see if swichting of partial statesaving solves the issue?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I use PF 5.2.6.

Comment: After setting partial state saving to false it work 3 times. Then a very short NPE comes up. Complete stack trace: `15:39:14,801 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:9090-4) java.lang.NullPointerException
15:39:14,801 SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (http-/0.0.0.0:9090-4) null: java.lang.NullPointerException`